Keycloak Idp Application Multiple Sessions Terminate
I have an application integrated with Keycloak 19. On password update I want to terminate all sessions a user is logged in from multiple devices/browsers, just like gmail when changing a password it logs out a user from all places user is logged in from. I have implemented a listener but it removes all sessions from keycloak but browser sessions are not killed. Any idea how can I achieve this.
Thanks
